# React put query string into form's value attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, virtual-dom

I have a search page, `something/search?q=foo`, whenever im at this page I want to put `foo` in my form's value tag. (Not for search purposes, I have a fully functioning search bar, I just want to show the client the last thing he searched for).

I've gotten the search term with: `(window.location.href.indexOf("?q") != -1) ? window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("?q") + 3) : ''`, this works, although when putting it into the forms value tag, react blocks immediately, it doesn't let me write anything into the input field. I think this is because it updates to this string super fast and you don't see it happening.

How would I achieve this, to update my form's value one time and thats it?

Here is my simplified code:

```
<input type="search" name="q" id="q" value={(window.location.href.indexOf("?q") != -1) ? window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("?q") + 3) : ''} <--- This is where I want to put the search string
```

What i've tried so far is this:

```
this.state = {
   value:''
}

...

handleTitle = (s) => {
   this.setState({value:s})
}

...

<input ... value={this.state.value} onChange={this.HandleTitle((window.location.href.indexOf("?q") != -1) ? window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("?q") + 3) : '')}
```

this results in infinite state updates

Comment: do you have used any type of router on your application? Router can easily provide that query.

Comment: getting the search term is not the problem, the problem is how to put it into the value field

Comment: update your question please. Show us the code how you are doing it? 
I would say put a state for the value field. Use useEffect and set the query term. And put that input as a value to your input field.

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives me infinite state updates and the app crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway if you want to access the `q` natively.
**Working example**
https://8zwht.csb.app/?q=test

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const search = new URL(window.location).searchParams;
    const term = search.get("q");
    if (term)
      this.setState({
        value: term
      });
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        value={this.state.value}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: yes, ComponentDidMount was what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you get the value of the search-param when the component mounts, and store it in the component's local state. Then read/update the value from state. Something like:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    setSearch(new URLSearchParams(new URL(window.location.href).search).get('q'));
}, []);

return (
     <intput type="text" value={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
);
```

I've not tested it, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: thank you, although currently this project doesn't use hooks, this is helpful aswell.

Comment: I wrote it before you updated your post, so I did not have any context when writing my answer. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to provide a more concrete answer if you share the code or gist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).